# Search by entity ID

Tags: product, magento-1.8, search

I want to add the ability to be able to search for products by entity id.

How would I go about editing the catalog search module to support this feature?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Which version of Magento? What search engine are you using?

Comment: Is Magento ver. 1.8.0.0, modify this functions and nothing works, tried here: addSearchFilter , _ getAttributesCollection. in Collection.php

Comment: On a very brief level, you'll need to make entity_id attribute searchable via code. It will be done at 1.) When preparing indexes, and 2.) When performing actual query.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to add code in preparing indexes, but not found the function for this, could you give me the function name please? for 1 or 2 options? so I will try to changes the code in the correct function.

Comment: I'm working in FullText.php file and view for changes in _rebuildStoreIndex function, is it right?